# ggplot scale_x_discrete drops values in barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-col

(Hopefully) simple issue but I haven't found anything on SO that directly addresses the question.  I have a ggplot barplot. x-axis are integers 0 through 10, y is percentages.  I want the bars to be explicitly labeled as 0, 1, 2, ... 10 on the x-axis, but when I use `scale_x_discrete` the values disappear.  Code below.

````
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)


#define Girl child as binomial success

#create dataframe of probability of K girls in N children, N=1 to 10 children

girl_probability_df <- 
  #create exhaustive list of 1 to 10 children, 1 to 10 girls
  tidyr::crossing(
    Number_Children = seq(1,10,1),
    Number_Girls = seq(0,10,1)) %>%
  #filter to just rows where the number of girls is less than or equal to number of children!
  dplyr::filter(Number_Girls <= Number_Children) %>%
  #find probability of that number of girls, in that number of children
  #dbinom is the R function that finds the probability of that number of girls, in that number of children,
  #with a 50% chance ("prob", for probability) of a child being a girl or boy
  dplyr::mutate(Probability = dbinom(x=Number_Girls,size=Number_Children,prob=0.5))

#barplot of probability
barplot_allkids <- ggplot2::ggplot(data=girl_probability_df,aes(x=Number_Girls,y=Probability)) +
geom_col() + facet_wrap(~Number_Children)+
#need to fix xlabel
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=seq(0,10,1))+
scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  ggtitle("Probability of Number of Girls, by Number of Total Children") +
  xlab("Number of Girls") +
  ylab("Probability")
barplot_allkids```
````

Comment: Try with `scale_x_continuous` as your x var is a numeric.

Comment: @stefan yep that's it. Thanks